# MySql Truncate should delete before insert loop but acts also in that loop

Tags: php, mysql, truncate, insert-into

im stuck here. i want to empty an existing table before inserting a loop of queries. but the result only gives me the last loop of the query back. so the truncate command also acts in that loop. somebody can tell me why? here is what i've got so far.

```
<?PHP
    if(isset($_POST["data"])) {
    $grpData = $_POST["data"];

    require_once('../mysql_connect.php');

    try {
        $dlt = $dbc->prepare("TRUNCATE TABLE table1");
        $dlt->execute();

        $stmt = $dbc->prepare("INSERT INTO table1 (trn,rnd,grp,gndprx,rce) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)");

        $stmt->bind_param("siiii", $trn,$rnd,$grp,$gndprx,$rce);

        foreach($grpData as $d){
                $trn = $d[0];
                $rnd = intval($d[1]);
                $grp = intval($d[2]);
                $gndprx = intval($d[3]);
                $rce = intval($d[4]);

                $stmt->execute();
        }

    }

    catch(PDOException $ex) {

        $dbc->rollBack();
        echo $ex->getMessage();
    }



    $dbc->close();
}
?>
```

Comment: try putting your insert code inside the foreach loop.

Comment: thx for the answer, but i get the same result.

Comment: did you debug your code ? are you sure the first iteration of loop inserted ?

Comment: you need to loop over the `insert`..

Comment: yes, everthing works fine without the truncate statement. with the statement the table emptys before every iteration. i tested your suggestions but i get the same results. :/  if i try the statement without prepare. `$dbc->exec("TRUNCATE TABLE table1");` i get an error...sry i dont know why--

Comment: i debugged the `$dlt` and it gets called every iteration. i think this is the problem. how to get the truncate statement out of the loop. the rest works fine. any ideas?... i tried `$dbc->query("TRUNCATE TABLE ".$rTable);` with no success...

Answer (score 1):

You have to bind the params inside the loop

```
    foreach($grpData as $d){
            $trn = $d[0];
            $rnd = intval($d[1]);
            $grp = intval($d[2]);
            $gndprx = intval($d[3]);
            $rce = intval($d[4]);
            $stmt->bind_param("siiii", $trn,$rnd,$grp,$gndprx,$rce);
            $stmt->execute();
    }
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but i get the same result. only the last loop gets inserted into the table. :/ without the truncate my code works perfect.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this ?

```
    require_once('../mysql_connect.php');

    try {
         $dbc->exec("TRUNCATE TABLE table1");
         $stmt = $dbc->prepare("INSERT INTO table1 (trn,rnd,grp,gndprx,rce) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)");

        foreach($grpData as $d){
                $trn = $d[0];
                $rnd = intval($d[1]);
                $grp = intval($d[2]);
                $gndprx = intval($d[3]);
                $rce = intval($d[4]);
                $stmt->bind_param("siiii", $trn,$rnd,$grp,$gndprx,$rce);
                $stmt->execute();
        }

    }

    catch(PDOException $ex) {

        $dbc->rollBack();
        echo $ex->getMessage();
    }

    $dbc->close();

} ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

All what you have suggested is right. It was my mistake. i got it! i forgot that i called the php script with an ajax call which is embedded in a diffrent loop. so i mad a second ajax call for the truncate statement outside that loop and all works fine. thanks for your help.